# How to set action bar and left drawer attributes for fragments according to their types

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have various types of fragment in my application and there are 3 icons on ActionBar (filter, refresh and sort) but I don't want to show all 3 icons in each of the fragments. I have to show only some of them according to the fragment.

Similar thing I want to do with left drawer. On some fragments I want to show left drawer whereas don't want to display left drawer on others.

I have a Activity class in my application on which I am attaching these fragments and currently I am handling these two things in this class and code has become mess with if-else conditions.

So right now I am checking fragment name and then setting action bar icons and left drawer attributes according to it.

Please tell me a better way to do it( preferably to handle this in Fragment itself)

Thanks

Comment: Hello dear, you can't edit the activity from inside fragment but i have discussed the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fragments have access to their activity through [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) function which will return non-null activity after [onAttach()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29) is called (and before [onDetach()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDetach%28%29)). Once the fragment has the activity it can tell it to do whatever you were doing right in the activity manually with checks, including changing the action bar buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the options depending on the fragment, you can simply do the following:

Add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to the `onCreate()` method of the fragment and tell the Activity to redraw its options menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Next override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method to inflate the options that you want for your fragment.

```
// No support library - support library api slightly different
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Add Fragment menu elements to Activity menu elements
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.myfragmentmenu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Finally make sure to capture all option items in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method of your activity.
(Important note: make sure to replace fragments instead of adding them. Otherwise `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will be called for each fragment.)

In order to disable and enable the drawer, you can add the following method to your Activity and call it from your fragment:

```
public void toggleDrawer(boolean enabled) {
    if (enabled) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project from a sample project called ActionBarCombat and also download this sample application here http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html

I once combined the two to come up with an application has action bar attributes as well as left drawer

Answer (score 0):

To structure your code a bit why don't you create some methods in your activity like displayRefreshIcon(boolean visible) in which you handle the visibly of these items.

From your fragment you can call these methods (like frangulyan suggests) through the getActivity() function. 
    If (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MyActivity) {
        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).displayRefreshIcon(true);
    }

Answer (score 0):

In main thread or usual it is somehow impossible to do make changes in the activity itself, because fragments are separated module who are attached with activities but not the part of them. 
But there is a shortcut that is to send message (handler) to activity to update the show the respective actionbar components
(most probably if you are using this fragment only for specific activity).

Answer (score 0):

There you should make a base fragment and each fragment should extend baseFragment and at onResume method you have to check instance of Fragment then according to them you can update actionBar View.

Answer (score 0):

Using any type of fragment, you should just have access to the methods (you have to override them): onCreateOptionsMenu, onPrepareOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected. These methods should provide you with plenty of handles to create a menu per fragment. You could create a menu layout file per fragment and handle them in the method designed to do so. The methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.overviewmenu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```